# What is the status of 'Sign in with LinkedIn' product (now deprecated)

Tags: linkedin-api

Moodle has been using Sign in with LinkedIn for some time and we've just been informed that it's deprecated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin) and we're trying to update our code accordingly. The replacement (Sign in with LinkedIn OIDC) is working okay (outside of some small issues which aren't spec-compliant) but we're so far unable to find any information on whether the deprecated sso method is still functioning, and if so, for how long (i.e. what's the deprecation time frame).

What I've tried:

- I've tried accessing the developer portal to add the legacy (deprecated) product to test whether it's still functional, but am unable to add it there.
- I've read the docs linked above and that doesn't provide the information either.

Can anyone (preferably someone who works for LinkedIn) provide further information about this deprecated sso method, specifically:

1. Is the deprecated product still functional for existing customers/integrations? (I'm unable to test this because I can't add that legacy product in the developer portal any more)
2. If so, how long is this going to be functional for, before being switched off entirely?

LinkedIn support directed me here, btw. Please don't just suggest using the OIDC method - we are using this for new installs. This question is specifically around the deprecated sso method.

Comment: If LinkedIn support cannot answer this, I suppose nobody can (or you contacted to wrong support channel)

Comment: LinkedIn support said, and I quote: 
"They are not a team that is usually facing the customers so you would need to direct your queries to the link here: https://developer.linkedin.com/support/stackoverflow.

Then our team can review and assist in more detail there. Apologies again for the confusion and inconvenience here."